# Why does np.linspace(1,5,5, dtype = int, endpoint=False) result in an array that contains 1 twice?

Tags: python, numpy

While looking to replicate:

```
In [61]: np.arange(0,5)
Out[61]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

using `np.linspace()`, I observed:

```
In [70]: np.linspace(1,5,5, dtype = int, endpoint=False)
Out[70]: array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Why does `np.linspace()` include the value **1** twice in this case?

Comment: Is it because I am forcing the dtype to be int, so numpy is constrained?

Comment: You're asking for 5 integers between 1 and 5 (not inclusive).  Unfortunately, there are only 4 integers in that range, so one of them has to be repeated...

Comment: @Pyderman - Numpy isn't constrained in that regard - you are putting the constrain (`dtype=int`) on the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because linspace is defined on floats and returns in your case:

```
np.linspace(1,5,5, endpoint=False)
array([ 1. ,  1.8,  2.6,  3.4,  4.2])
```

then using `int` as dtype just rounds down giving you the result with two `1`:

```
array([ 1 ,  1,  2,  3,  4])
```

Btw: Using `np.arange` might be better suited if you want to create `arrays` containing `integer`:

```
np.arange(1,5)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4])
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test because dtype was introduced in 1.9 and I have 1.8. Without dtype, I get:

```
np.linspace(1,5,5, endpoint=False)
array([ 1. ,  1.8,  2.6,  3.4,  4.2])
```

Then

```
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

is a round down of this.

You'd get what you expect using

```
np.linspace(1,5,5, dtype=int)
```

but as suggested in another answer, you'd be better off using np.arange().

Comment: Or `np.linspace(1, 5, 5, dtype=int)` (`endpoint = True` which is the default).

Comment: Edited. Thx @mgilson.

Answer (score 0):

For `a - b + 1 < n`, it is [impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) for `np.linspace(a, b, n, dtype=int)` to give unique values.

However, if `a - b + 1 > n`, the intermediate values may be rounded down (e.g. `3.9 -> 3`). To get a more evenly-spaced array, use this instead:

```
np.linspace(a, b, n).round().astype(int)
```